# Together we make a country!

Tags: riddle

A bunch of guests are invited to a talk show.

> Host: Welcome! Would each of you give some brief introduction about yourself?
>
> Guest 1: Sure. I like to read War and Peace. It's a story of my own life.
>
> Guest 2: I have a good buddy. He's very active but I am way too lazy. That's probably why every time people take both of us in together, I'm always the one who gets kicked out immediately.
>
> Guest 3: I'm black, but I often mingle with white guys. They say it's good for health.
>
> Guest 4: I am right before guy before me.
>
> Guest 5: Ich wurde am 9. November 1994 geboren.
>
> Guest 6: I'm an IT guy. I have extensive experience working with iPhone, Xbox, Thinkpad, etc. Need my service? Call me at 737-373-7373
>
> Guest 7: I am two floors below the guy below me.
>
> Guest 8: Have you been to Yellowstone? I lo~~ve Yellowstone! Oh yeah, that fascinating smell!
>
> Host: Okay...perfect. So, why are you all here today?
>
> All: Together we make a country!

**What country is it?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each guest is

> a chemical element.

They are:

> Uranium (U): used in war (nuclear bombs) and in peace (nuclear energy).
> Nitrogen (N): inert gas, nitrogen is exhaled but more reactive oxygen is used in the body.
> Iodine (I): purple-black solid, salt is often iodized to prevent iodine deficiency.
> Tellurium (Te): one before iodine.
> Darmstadtium (Ds): synthesized in Germany on 9 November 1994.
> Tantalum (Ta): atomic number 73, used to make electronic components.
> Tellurium (Te): two rows below sulfur.
> Sulfur (S): the smell of hot springs comes from sulfides.

and together they make

> UNITeDsTaTeS (United States).

Comment: Whoa you're amazingly fast! Or is my problem too easy XD I can't even accept your answer yet!

Comment: @f'' How did you get to each conclusion?

Comment: @f" How did you come up with Tantalum for guest #6?